# How to use gzip in receiving request return and compress in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, gzip, fetch-api

I want to compress the response when using `fetch()`(the response size is too large and lead to error).

In Linux-curl, we can use `--compressed`. In PHP curl, we can use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate")`.

How to do the same when using `fetch()` in Javascript?

I got the following error when receiving too large response:

```
TypeError: terminated
    at Fetch.onAborted (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11442:53)
    at Fetch.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Fetch.terminate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10695:14)
    at Object.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11537:36)
    at Request.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8310:31)
    at errorRequest (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10378:17)
    at TLSSocket.onSocketClose (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9811:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at node:net:337:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:631:7) {
  [cause]: SocketError: other side closed
      at TLSSocket.onSocketEnd (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9790:26)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1376:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_SOCKET',
    socket: {
      localAddress: '172.17.0.2',
      localPort: 48798,
      remoteAddress: '13.232.157.196',
      remotePort: 443,
      remoteFamily: 'IPv4',
      timeout: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 1594938,
      bytesRead: 12318698
    }
  }
}
```

Sometimes, instead of the server terminate, I also get **502 status**:

```
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 502,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 30458327.747774124,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 30458327.747774124,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 166,
      decodedBodySize: 166,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'Bad Gateway',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ URL {} ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(5) {
      'date' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'content-length' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'server' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

Comment: Browsers handle the compression automatically for you. As long as your server is configured for compression it should just work.

Comment: I am using nodejs to fetch the data through API, and I faced error probably due to too much receiving data size. @Evert

Comment: Maybe you should focus on the error for your question. If it's a large response, consider not storing everything in memory.

Comment: Besides storing everything in memory, is there any other way to store the response? @Evert

Comment: How large is the response? Is it some file, or is it some API response? To answer this question better it helps to get some details.

Comment: It is some API response, and the two compress methods are provided by the API provider, he said the over limit response probably leads to the error and told me to compress the response, however, I don't know how to do it in nodejs, I will definitely add the response error code to the question if I can reproduce it again. @Evert

Comment: I have added the error that I faced because of not zipping the response data to the question, please check, thank you. @Evert

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you use axios library for sending HTTP requests because it does the compression automatically. here are the links

Documents:
https://axios-http.com/docs/intro

install via npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: If I simply use `axios.post()`, it will do the compression automatically for me?

Comment: Axios does not do this automatically, the browser does. You don't need axios for this (or for almost anything else).